# Content of textarea is not being delivered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML with one of several radio buttons:

```
<div>

        <input type="radio" value="3">  <label>Some random text.</label>

        <div class="reason">
            <p>Please state reason:</p>
            <textarea id="reason_3" size="60">Reason stated.</textarea>
        </div>  

</div>
```

And here is my jQuery that doesn't work:

```
var option = 3;
var reason = $("input[value='" + option + "']").next(".reason").has("textarea").val();
```

My goal is to put the content of the textarea into the variable `reason`. My jQuery code somehow doesn't achieve this and when I write `alert(reason)` the message I get is `undefined`.... I need the content of the textarea for a php script...

What's wrong here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need :

```
$("input[value='" + option + "']").siblings(".reason").find("textarea").val()
```

or

```
$("input[value='" + option + "']").siblings(".reason textarea").val()
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fywd9/)**

Answer (score 5):

you need to use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) - also instead of [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/), you need to use [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
var option = 3;
var reason = $("input[value='" + option + "']").siblings(".reason").find("textarea").val();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C3m2y/)

- The `.reason` element is not the next sibling of the input element, it is the next of next element, so either you can use `.next().next('.reason')` or use `siblings()`
- `.has()` is used to filter the element set against an descendant selector, not to find an descendant element - so use `.find()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you already have an `id` assigned to your text area, why don't you directly use that?

```
var reason = $("#reason_3").val();
```

---

Or something like this :

```
$("#reason_"+option).val();
```

Comment: Yes, `$("#reason_" + option).val();`.